# Bootstrap responsive panel with a wide dropdown in it, breaking mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a responsive Panel that in Mobile becomes scrollable because the dropdown text content is too long.

Mobile dropdown (at least in iOS) only displays a portion of the selection anyways when you select the dropdown.

What's the best way to handle this?

[Sample Bootply Here](http://www.bootply.com/2StJI8CsLX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a styling issue for IOS rather than Bootstrap, but it looks as though you just need to add an optgroup tag after your last option:

http://www.bootply.com/Xw8pzjoACx

Set the dropdown width in CSS to 100% to stop it overlapping the container.